# TikZ externalize vs. the list of figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I'm using `pgf` in combination with `tikzexternalize` for every plot.
Now it's the first time I want to create a list of figures in latex and I
realised, that the externalize function does not well behave in combination with `groupplot` and `subcaption`. MWE:

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7,max space between ticks=50pt}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

    \usetikzlibrary{external}
    %    \tikzexternalize[prefix=TikZPictures/]


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \section{Hello World}
    \begin{figure}[!t]
        \centering
        \input{plots.tikz}
        \caption{Two beautiful plots.}
        \label{more plots}
    \end{figure}

    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```

plots.tikz:

```
% !TeX root = ../../main.tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1,
        horizontal sep =0.1\textwidth},
    height=0.45\textwidth,width=0.45\textwidth,]


    \nextgroupplot[ylabel=$y_1$,
        xlabel=$x$,]
    \addplot[blue,domain=0:5,] {exp(-0.5*x)*sin(rad(x))};

    \node[text width=1cm,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west] (Subplot a) at (rel axis cs: 0,1)
    {\subcaption[Second plot first part]{\label{2. plot a}}};


    \nextgroupplot[ylabel=$y_2$,
        xlabel=$x$,]
    \addplot[blue,domain=-1:1,] {-x*x + 2*x};
    \node[text width=1cm,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west] (Subplot a) at (rel axis cs: 0,1)
    {\subcaption[Second plot first part]{\label{2. plot b}}};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

When I use `tikzexternalize` the subfigures disapear from the list of figures. Is there a workaround. Complete remove `tikzexternalize` is not an option, but I think for the final version I could do it that way, if its the
only solution.

Comment: I am not sure but I think that you need to either organise the figure so that the labels are not part of the `tikzpicture` itself or to use one of the non-automatic modes for externalisation such as `list and make` or `make` or whatever. The manual is somewhat ambiguous at this point, but I suspect your code falls under the exception discussed at the bottom of 597 which explains that you need to proceed as for `case a)` which involves non-automatic creation of the external images. Personally, I'd probably go for pulling `\label` out of the picture, but I don't know your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the `\label`s occur within the `tikzpicture` environment. (See bottom page 597 of TikZ's manual, although it is not very clear here.)

Two ways to avoid the problem:

1. Use 'method (a)' to create the images i.e. use a different externalisation mode. This involves creating the pictures in a separate step e.g. running a `Makefile`. TikZ can write that file for you automatically, though. In this case, you set the externalisation mode to something like `list and make`.
2. Take the `\label`s out of the `tikzpicture` environment. For example, use the `subfigure` environment rather than `\subcaption`.

Personally, I'd go for method 2 but you may have different desiderata. In any case, here's one way to implement method 2 which allows externalisation as you currently have it configured, so that the images are created automatically as part of normal compilation (though with `--shell-escape`, of course).

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.tikz}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1,horizontal sep =0.1\textwidth},height=0.95\linewidth,width=0.95\linewidth,]
        \nextgroupplot[ylabel=$y_1$,
        xlabel=$x$,]
        \addplot[blue,domain=0:5,] {exp(-0.5*x)*sin(rad(x))};
      \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[Second plot first part]{\label{2. plot b}}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1,horizontal sep =0.1\textwidth},height=0.95\linewidth,width=0.95\linewidth,]
        \nextgroupplot[ylabel=$y_2$,
        xlabel=$x$,]
        \addplot[blue,domain=-1:1,] {-x*x + 2*x};
      \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[Second plot first part]{\label{2. plot a}}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7,max space between ticks=50pt}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
\begin{figure}[!t]
  \centering
  \input{\jobname.tikz}
  \caption{Two beautiful plots.}
  \label{more plots}
\end{figure}

\ref{2. plot b} \ref{2. plot a}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

[image: subfigures and externalisation]

Comment: I'm using subcaptions instead of subfigures. so i can avoid additional labels below my figures. What I thought of, is there a way, to manually tell LaTex to create a entry in the .tof file?

Comment: @manthano In that case, I would use the manual externalisation method. However, you can, yes, manually add entries using `\addcontentsline{lof}{<level>}{<text>}`.

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow; thank you for your effort.

Comment: @manthano OK. It should work fine. It is just like adding a line manually to the table of contents but you write it to the list of figures file instead. Put it within the `figure` so that you get the right page numbers even if the figure floats somewhere else ;).